# Rails 5.2 ActiveAdmin deep nested objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested, activeadmin, show

I have this scheme: Course->Segments->Questions.
Course has many segments and segments has many questions.
I added segment_type attribute to segment model so I can show/hide question model depends on the type (video or quiz).
I managed to write the form in courses.rb and I got access to questions through course.

I'm having a problem with showing question attributes in show page even when I searched 3-4 hours on google for answer. **[Here is a screenshot of the show page](https://image.ibb.co/jVEXgK/Screen_Shot_2018_08_06_at_13_07_10.png)**

I wrote accept_nested_attribute in all the models so this is not the problem. I can edit, create and delete courses, segments and questions, it's just I can't see in the show the data relevant to questions.

**EDIT:** I know that the relations works fine in rails console and I have data in questions (it suppose to display the last segment's questions)

**these are my models:**

```js
class Course < ApplicationRecord
  validates :title ,presence: true
  validates :author ,presence: true

  has_many :segments, inverse_of: :course, :dependent => :destroy, :autosave => true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :segments, :allow_destroy => true
end


class Segment < ApplicationRecord
  validates :course_id ,presence: true
  validates :data ,presence: true, if: :segment_is_video?
  validates :segment_type ,presence: true
  validates_presence_of :course

  belongs_to :course
  has_many :questions, inverse_of: :segments, :dependent => :destroy, :autosave => true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :questions, :allow_destroy => true

  def self.segment_type
    {"Video": "Video", "Quiz": "Quiz"}
  end

   def segment_is_video?
     segment_type == 'Video'
   end

end


class Question < ApplicationRecord
  validates :question ,presence: true
  validates :answer1 ,presence: true
  validates :answer2 ,presence: true
  validates :answer3 ,presence: true
  validates :answer4 ,presence: true
  validates :correct ,presence: true
  validates_presence_of :segment

  belongs_to :segment
end
```

**this is courses.rb:**

```js
ActiveAdmin.register Course do
  permit_params :id, :title, :autor,
                segments_attributes: [:id, :unit_id, :unit_title, :name, :segment_type, :data, :_destroy, :_create, :_update, questions_attributes: [:id, :question, :answer1, :answer2, :answer3, :answer4, :correct, :_destroy, :_create, :_update]]

  config.sort_order = 'id_asc'

  member_action :segments do
    @segments = resource.segments

  end

  index do
    column :id
    column :title
    column :author
    actions
  end

  show do
      panel "Course Segments" do
      h3 "Videos"
       table_for resource.segments.where('segment_type = "Video"') do
         column :id
         column :name
         column :data
       end

       # Here it's only displaying id and name values, but the others no.
       h3 "Quizes"
        table_for resource.segments.where('segment_type = "Quiz"') do
          column :id
          column :name
          column :question
          column :answer1
          column :answer2
          column :answer3
          column :answer4
          column :correct
        end
     end
    active_admin_comments
  end

sidebar "Course Details", only: :show do
  attributes_table_for course do
    row :title
    row :author
  end
end

form do |f|
  tabs do
    tab 'Basic Info' do
      f.inputs "Course details" do
        f.input :title
        f.input :author
      end
    end

    tab 'Content' do
      f.inputs "Segments" do
        f.has_many :segments, heading: false, allow_destroy: true do |s|
          s.input :unit_id
          s.input :unit_title
          s.input :name
          s.input :segment_type, as: :select, collection: Segment.segment_type, input_html: { class: 'select-type' }

          s.input :data, label: 'Url', :as => :string, input_html: { class: 'video-tab' }

          s.has_many :questions, heading: false, allow_destroy: true do |q|
            q.input :question, input_html: { class: 'quiz-tab' }
            q.input :answer1, input_html: { class: 'quiz-tab' }
            q.input :answer2, input_html: { class: 'quiz-tab' }
            q.input :answer3, input_html: { class: 'quiz-tab' }
            q.input :answer4, input_html: { class: 'quiz-tab' }
            q.input :correct, input_html: { class: 'quiz-tab' }, as: :select, collection: [1,2,3,4]
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
    f.actions
end

end
```

Comment: The segment has no 'question' column or association, so how should your table display it? Every segment has_many questions, so you need to iterate over them to display question, answer1 etc attributes for every question. May be it is better to create a separate panel for every quiz segment?

Comment: but segment_attributes have question_attributes, can I get somehow an access to it?

Comment: Not sure if I understood you? `Segment` model has a separate question column? Could you please add schema of these 3 models?

Comment: no, Segment only have a has_many :question relationship, but in courses.rb which I posted in the original post I wrote question_attributes in segment_attributes like that:   segments_attributes: [:id, :unit_id, :unit_title, :name, :segment_type, :data, :_destroy, :_create, :_update, questions_attributes: [:id, :question, :answer1, :answer2, :answer3, :answer4, :correct, :_destroy, :_create, :_update]] . I can get to this data in the form and I can create new question. delete and save so I can get access to question attributes I just don't know how

Comment: You can't, it's just for form. It means that you have questions attributes for a separate segment, e.g. segment_1 has_many questions with its attributes: [question_1: {id: 1, question: 'Name', answer1: 'Name, etc}, question_2: {id: 2, question: 'Name', answer1: 'Name, etc}, etc], and you can save a segment with all his questions at once.

Comment: so how can I get this data? I don't want to add resource because I don't want another tab, I want that the access wil be only in courses

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177503/discussion-between-vasilisa-and-ofir-sasson).